# C# Regex - Accept spaces in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have an application which needs some verifications for some fields. One of them is for a last name which can be composed of 2 words. In my regex, I have to accept these spaces so I tried a lot of things but I did'nt find any solution.

Here is my regex :

```
@"^[a-zA-Zàéèêçñ\s][a-zA-Zàéèêçñ-\s]+$"
```

The `\s` are normally for the spaces but it does not work and I got this error message :

```
parsing "^[a-zA-Zàéèêçñ\s][a-zA-Zàéèêçñ-\s]+$" - Cannot include class \s in character range.
```

ANy idea guys?

Comment: Other topic, but have a look into [Unicode properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop). `\p{L}`, this is matching a letter in any language, so your expression would look like `@"^[\p{L}\s][\p{L}\s-]+$"` is a lot nicer and you don't have to think about each special letter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`-` denotes a character range, just as you use `A-Z` to describe *any character between A and Z*. Your regex uses `ñ-\s` which the engine tries to interpret as *any character between ñ and \s* -- and then notices, that `\s` doesn't make a whole lot of sense there, because `\s` itself is only an *abbreviation* for any whitespace character.

That's where the error comes from.

To get rid of this, you should always *put `-` at the **end*** of your character class, if you want to include the `-` literal character:

```
@"^[a-zA-Zàéèêçñ\s][a-zA-Zàéèêçñ\s-]+$"
```

This way, the engine knows that `\s-` is not a character range, but the two characters `\s` and `-` seperately.

The other way is to escape the `-` character:

```
@"^[a-zA-Zàéèêçñ\s][a-zA-Zàéèêç\-\s]+$"
```

So now the engine interprets `ñ\-\s` not as a character range, but as *any of the characters `ñ`, `-` or `\s`*. Personally, though I always try to avoid escaping as often as possible, because IMHO it clutters up and needlessly stretches the expression in length.

Comment: Escaping is less brittle. Say you have a character class for operations: `[+-]`. Another programmer may change it to `[+-*/]`, breaking the pattern.

Comment: I agree, but you can argue that in any way. Say you have a pattern `[+\-*]` because you can't do divisions. Some day you can do it, and another programmer changes it to `[+/-*]` because he thinks you just got the slash the wrong way around. Off goes your escaping. So, this is really not an argument for any of the ways. I just value readability a little more, especially in regex because they're complicated enough as it is.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the last `-` character - `ñ-\s` is parsed like the range `a-z`:

```
@"^[a-zA-Zàéèêçñ\s][a-zA-Zàéèêçñ\-\s]+$"
```

See also on Regex Storm: [`[a-\s]`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5ba-%5cs%5d&i=a) , [`[a\-\s]`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5ba%5c-%5cs%5d&i=a)

Answer (score 0):

[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z\s]+$", ErrorMessage = "Only alphabetic characters and spaces are allowed.")]

This works