# Regex Convert from Js to C#

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

How can I convert to following Js regex into C#

```
let regex = /^([+]?\d{1,2}[.-\s]?)?(\d{3}[.-]?){2}\d{4}$/;
```

This patterns matches with following international mobile phone numbers

```
044668180099,
+49-691-234-5678,
+90-537-325-2345,
90-537-566-7152,
```

I want to do same matches wirh C#

Please advice

Comment: check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.8 there is a solution

Comment: Try with this: @"^([+]?\d{1,2}[.\-\s]?)?(\d{3}[.-]?){2}\d{4}$"

Comment: So just use your *regex string pattern* as is in C#, keeping in mind that C# does not support regex literals.

Comment: also check this answer for spaces: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16077677/2050306

Answer (score 2):

Remove '/' at the start and the end of the string.

```
Regex.Match(yourline, @"^([+]?\d{1,2}[.\-\s]?)?(\d{3}[.-]?){2}\d{4}$");
```

[See also this page about Regex.Match() from the microsoft docs for more overloads.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Match_System_String_System_String_)

Comment: Doesn't work: 'RegExParseException: Invalid Pattern'.  @robert's answer in the comments above is correct

Comment: Oops, I forgot to escape the '-' character. Updated it.

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't actually try it, but it's right now :-)

Comment: No, I did not. ;p